# How to find the location where image data is stored in TIFF file?

Tags: python, tiff

I have a large SVS file. I want to use tifffile to process, but the transmission speed is too slow.I want to segment SVS, first transmit part of the image data for processing.So I need to find the image data location of SVS file, and then start segmentation from here.Can tifffile locate the location of image data?

Comment: Surely your question title should ask how to find where TIFF image is located in SVS file?

Comment: the position of image data in SVS

Comment: Your question is tagged Python. Where is the Python?

Comment: You can use tifffile to [read parts of the image via Zarr](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/375d97f62df6482142b51f1b38a49bdd24d18a60/tifffile/tifffile.py#L632-L643). If the file is stored on a file system that tifffile does not support, export the TIFF files to a fsspec ReferenceFileSystem JSON files and open those using fsspec and Zarr. See also [kerchunk](https://github.com/fsspec/kerchunk).

Comment: The location of the (usually encoded) image data is stored in the `dataoffsets` and `databytecounts` attributes of `tifffile.TiffPage` instances. See [this example](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/375d97f62df6482142b51f1b38a49bdd24d18a60/tifffile/tifffile.py#L618-L630).

Comment: Very useful. It seems that I need to add complete header information to restore the image

Answer (score 0):

This is the scheme I have verified

```py
from tifffile import TiffFile
k=0
with TiffFile('name.svs') as tif:
    fh = tif.filehandle
    for page in tif.pages:
        print(page)
        for index, (offset, bytecount) in enumerate(
            zip(page.dataoffsets, page.databytecounts)
        ):
            _ = fh.seek(offset)
            data = fh.read(bytecount)
            if k==10:
                print(offset)
            if k==100:
                print(offset)
            k+=1
```

In this way, you can get the location of each tile in the file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).